# Upload File into Personal Google Drive Account Instead of Service Account (Google Drive API)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I've write this code to upload an XLSX file to Google Drive using the service account mechanism.

However, the file is being uploaded to the service account's drive instead of my personal drive. I've explored some articles and found suggestions to share the folder with the service account's email address.

```
Future uploadFileToGoogleDrive(String file) async {
    // Connect to
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = google_apis.DriveApi(client);

    // constants
    // const mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder';
    String folderID = 'SOME_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID';

    // Upload file(s)
    var fileToUpload = File(file);
    var media =
    google_apis.Media(fileToUpload.openRead(), fileToUpload.lengthSync());
    var driveFile = google_apis.File();

    // Filename preps
    // print(fileToUpload.path);
    // DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();
    // String dateNow = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(dateTimeNow);
    driveFile.name = file; // File path, name, and extension
    // driveFile.modifiedTime = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    driveFile.parents = [folderID]; // to specific folder

    var response = await drive.files.create(driveFile, uploadMedia: media);

    print('Uploaded as ${response.name}');
    }
```

Can anyone confirm if this is the correct approach and provide any additional guidance to make it uploaded to my personal drive folder?

Thanks!